# When does the clock for a husband annulling his wife's vows start?

Tags: halacha, time, nedarim-shevuot

A husband can annul his wife's vows that she makes, for a single calendar day after he hears it. This means that if he hears it at night, he has nearly 24 hours until the next sunset; in the morning, only around 12 until sunset, and very little time in the evening. ([Rambam Hilchot Nedarim 12:15](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=6&hilchos=31&perek=12&halocha=15&hilite=))

Let's say that it is an hour until sunset, and the husband is quite busy. Someone comes and tells him, "your wife made a vow." Can the husband then say, "don't tell me what it is until after sunset, so that i have another day to decide"?

In other words, does the clock start from when he hears *that the vow exists*, or is it from *when he hears the content* of the vow?

Comment: Re your specific case ("don't tell me...") see also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant date is the date when he hears who vowed and what they vowed. (Rambam Nedarim [12:21](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=5683), Shulchan Arukh YD [234:21](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6667),[31-32](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x6669))