# What if you don't know whether something became muktzeh between twilight and nightfall?

Tags: shabbat, zemanim, muktzeh, chazaka

I am vaguely aware that there are certain cases in which an otherwise non-muktzeh object may become muktzeh, i.e., [by being on a certain base during twilight on Friday night](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/hashoneh-halachos/tues_07_02_13/). But if you don't know whether this happened, because you weren't watching that item for the 72 minutes between sunset and nightfall, do you have an obligation to ask others, or to perform your own detective-style investigation about the object, before moving it? 
Presumably, this could have happened to any movable object without your knowledge. 
Or could you just move it--

1. If you have no reason to think that such a thing happened (you simply don't know for sure that it didn't)...?
2. If you have some reason to think it might have happened, but you don't know for sure...?

*Hypothesis*: This is maybe a safek derabanan l'kulo (in some cases maybe even a safek safeika, because the base's status is also questionable).  However i would wonder if there were not factors like chazaka and rov involved. I am really out of my depths on all this though; thus, I ask the question.

Comment: More generally, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18202

Comment: The definition of "bein hashemoshos" is a matter of controversy. It may be shorter than 72 mins. But unless it is very short indeed, your question is still good. See http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/_lectureShiurText.cfm?shiurId=710224